# flask under nginx + uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

we're developing a flask application but after 4 hours trying to configure the server I can't figure it out.

Here's the thing:

- the vm is accessible through xx.xx.xx.xx:81
- on this server, my app is at : /var/hg/repositories/data/test.py

I'd like to access this application through xx.xx.xx.xx:81/ws

This is what I did with nginx :

```
 location = /var/hg/repositories/data { rewrite ^ /var/hg/repositories/data/; }
     location /ws { try_files $uri @ws; }
     location @ws {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /var/hg/repositories/data;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
     }
```

I have a yaml file to lunch uwsgi :

```
uwsgi:
  socket: 127.0.0.1:9090
  master: 1
  workers: 1
  chmod-socket: 666
  auto-procname: 1
  python-path: .
  pidfile: /tmp/uwsgi.pid
  daemonize: /var/log/uwsgi.log
  module: test:app
```

Going to xx.xx.xx.xx:81 gives me the classic nginx welcome message.

Going to xx.xx.xx.xx:81/ws gives me a 404.

What am I doing wrong?

after conf update, i have

> ```
>     location = /var/hg/repositories/data/
>     location /var/hg/repositories/data/ { try_files $uri @web }
>     location @ws {
>              uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
>     }
> ```

my uwsgi conf :

```
uwsgi:
  socket: unix:/tmp/uwsgi.lock
  master: 1
  workers: 1
  chmod-socket: 666
  auto-procname: 1
  pidfile: /tmp/uwsgi.pid
  deamonize: /var/log/uwsgi.log
  manage-script-name: true
  mount: /ws=/var/hg/repositories/data/test.py
  callable: app
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to "mount" the app in uWSGI, currently you have "mounted" it as empty SCRIPT_NAME

mount: /ws=test.py

callable: app

(remove the 'module' directive) will do the trick.

I suggest you to avoid nginx managing SCRIPT_NAME as it is not too smart about that, and using modifier1 30 is really an ugly hack.

Just remove both uwsgi_param and uwsgi_modifier1 from nginx and add manage-script-name: true to uWSGI

Comment: tanks for your help, situation in progess, now uswgi give me "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='/ws') (callable not found or import error)" error. FYI, my test.py is just a basic example found on flask homepage

Comment: i have edit my response, i think it was not clear that mount and callable have to be on different lines

Comment: i've update my initial post, ajusting my configuration. now uwsgi returns var/hg/repositories/data/test.py on /ws
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='/ws') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x96db410 pid: 21194 (default app) bu nothing append when i get xxx.xx.xx.xx:81/ws

Comment: your nginx config now looks strange, can you check it (for example the @web /@ws naming) and repaste ?